# Primefaces OverlayPanel inside composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay-6

I'm developing a composite component to centralize and reuse primefaces components:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:bridge="http://portletfaces.org/bridge"
xmlns:m3="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/m3jsf"
xmlns:Portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <p:overlayPanel id="idPanelloListaDatiFullScreen" dynamic="true" appendToBody="false" 
        styleClass="m3PanelListaDati" binding="#{m3DataTableBackingBean.bindingVarOverlay}" 
        rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
        </p:overlayPanel>   
        <p:panel id="idPanelloListaDati" styleClass="m3PanelListaDati" 
        rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
            <composite:insertChildren></composite:insertChildren>
        </p:panel>
    </span>
</composite:implementation>
```

And I use it in a view as:

```
<m3:myCompositePanel id="idCompositePanel/>
```

But when view is rendering an exception is trown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:567)
at org.primefaces.component.overlaypanel.OverlayPanelRenderer.encodeScript(OverlayPanelRenderer.java:67)
at org.primefaces.component.overlaypanel.OverlayPanelRenderer.encodeEnd(OverlayPanelRenderer.java:37)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:78)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.ViewHandlerCompatImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerCompatImpl.java:35)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
... 219 more
```

I'm using PirmeFaces 3.5.23, mojarra 2.1.21 and I'm developing a portlet in Liferay 6.1.3ga3 and bridge 3.1.3ga4

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Line 67 of the PrimeFaces OverlayPanelRenderer.java class is trying to resolve the value of the **for** attribute. It looks like you may have forgotten to specify a value for the for attribute in your p:overlayPanel.

Comment: Hi Neil,
Yes. I foolishly forgot it! Thank you so much